# Does Docker-Compose allow overwriting of ports when using extends?

Tags: docker-compose

See title. According to the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/extends/#extending-services):

> For the multi-value options ports, expose, external_links, dns, dns_search, and tmpfs, Compose concatenates both sets of values:

Is there any way to change this behavior? I have an entry that is extended by multiple other entries, and all but one of them use the same port. But the last one needs to use a different port, which means it should *replace* the ports.

Is there any way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as you can see here (https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/2260) this is an open issue with compose.